# Create a Dictionary of Multiple Lists with variable number

Tags: python

My lists are `data1` and `data2` and and I can successfully put two lists in a single dictionary. When I have an unknown number of these lists of files in a directory, how can I do this code for all these files?

For example I have `(data1,data2,data3,data4,...)`

```
final_dict = {key: value + data2[key]  for key, value in data1.items()}
```

Comment: `data1, data2` are themselves dictionaries, not lists. Please explain your goal more clearly.

Comment: yes,you suppose that data's are dictionary

Comment: i stored this data's in pickle object in a directory

Comment: So you want something like `{key: value + data2[key] + data3[key] + data4[key] for key, value in data1.items()}`? How does your example `final_dict` scale to multiple arrays?

Comment: I load those pickle files that I saved in the directory and run this code for them. My point is that when I have more of these data's, how do I run the following code for all these data's?

Comment: **You** need to define how to combine the lists together yourself. Right now it's not clear how they are to be merged into one dict.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and also read [tour].

Comment: Provide your current code that you are using to put two `lists` in a single `dictionary` so that we can understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the data1, data2 etc. are all dicts and that you have a list of these dicts. Here is a way of creating a final_dict which contains every key/value pair from all dicts in the list:

```
# Unknown number of dicts
data1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
data2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}

# List of the dicts
dict_list = [data1, data2]

final_dict = {}
for data_dict in dict_list:
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        final_dict[key] = value

print(final_dict )
```

Is this what you are after?

**Attempting to understand desired output**

I still don't understand how you want the output to look like. Let's try with an example. If data looks like this:

```
data1 = {'encodings':['UTF-8', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-32'],'names':['Unicode']}
data2 = {'encodings':['ISO 8859-1', 'EBCDIC', 'GB18030', 'ASCII'],'names':['8-bit']}
data3 = {'encodings':['Windows-1250', 'KOI8-R', 'GBK'],'names':['other']}
data_list = [data1, data2, data3]
```

How do you want the `final_dict` to look like with those input data?

Comment: my question is how is make "data2[key] + data3[key] + data4[key]+..." from my dictionaries

Comment: i get this error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Ok. Can you provide examples of what the data looks like and how you expect the result to look like.

Comment: final_dict = {key: value + data[1][key] + data[2][key] + data[3][key] + ... for key, value in daf[0].items()}    , my question is how i make data[1][key]+data[2][key] + data[3][key] + ... ??number of this sum is number of my lists length

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Did I understand it correctly that `data1` is a dict, and that `data2` is a dict? Then I would like to see what the data inside `data1` and `data2` looks like as well as how the data inside `final_dict` should look like.

Comment: data1,data2,data3,... are dictionary,for example data1={'encodings':[multiple encodings],'names':['john']}...i have multiple data's and these data's(data1,data2,data3,...) final_dict = {key: value + data2[key] + data3[key] +data4[key]+... for key, value in data1.items()} I know that using this code I can reach my goal
My problem is how to implement this code when I have a few data. I do not want to put these data in code like hardcode in this form.

Comment: I have added question about example data to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data dictionaries already stored in a list called `dict_list`:

```
final_dict = {key: value for data_dict in dict_list for key, value in data_dict.items()}
```

would do the same as [figbeam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172933/figbeam)'s answer. Although less verbose and arguably a little harder to read, it is closer to your proposed approach :) Maybe this helps, too.